# Where did this potential energy come from?

Tags: potential, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, spring, rotational-kinematics

I was reading a paper about Wilberforce Pendulum:
https://faraday.physics.utoronto.ca/IYearLab/WilberforceRefBerg2of8.pdf

This is the potential energy of (spring+weight with moment of inertia)

$V={{1}\over{2}}kz^2 + {{1}\over{2}} \delta\theta^2+ {{1}\over{2}}\epsilon z \theta$

where $k$ is the spring constant and $\delta$ is the torsion constant of the spring,

$z$ is the horizontal distance and $\theta$ is the angular displacement.

I understand all the terms except one the term ${{1}\over{2}}\epsilon z \theta$.

Where did this energy come from? Thank you!

Comment: Reading the text it seems that the coupling term $\frac{1}{2} \epsilon z \theta$ is postulated to model the interaction. He assumes this interaction. So the answer is that it pops out of nowhere

Comment: Look at Helix equations you find that $z=\epsilon\varphi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this problem you want a term which couples the $z$-movement with the $\theta$-movement, and *a term of the form $1/2\epsilon\theta z$ is the only **linear** one you can think of*, because there are no other. Then, after solving equations and motion and comparing the result with experiments, you would see if this linear term does the job and you would find the value of $\epsilon$ which makes them match. If not, you would have to start thinking about non linear couplings, which makes calculations way more complicated

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, why is it potential energy, not kinetic? Can't those two parameters be linked each other through kinetic energy?

Comment: It is a matter of definition. What we call kinetic energy are the terms of the form $1/2a\dot q^2$ in the Lagrangian, and potential energy is all the rest